# AJAX call return undefined

Tags: ajax

This AJAX call is returning "undefined". I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and why this isn't working:

```
var xmlfile;

 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'sample.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data){
    xmlfile = $(data);}
    });

console.log(xmlfile);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: its right  check the  file path is there file exists

Comment: by default ajax calls are async, change your call to `async:false`

Comment: @MattBall yes, you are absolutely correct! I did the same approach earlier, got confused this time!

Answer (score 3):

This is likely to be a timing issue since you're referring to the xmlFile variable before the call returns. Instead you have to move the reference into the success callback.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'sample.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data){
    xmlfile = data;
    console.log(xmlfile); 
    }
    });
```

Try the above.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'sample.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data){
    xmlfile =  data ;}
 });
```

or set the  `async : false,`

you can detect error/problem by debugging so you can see where are you doing wrong

like see `alert(data)` it it does it mean you are getting successful response by ajax call

Answer (score 0):

```
var xmlfile;

 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'sample.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    async : false,
    success: function(data){
    xmlfile = $(data);}
    });

console.log(xmlfile);
```

try This, you are getting undefined due to asyn call, your log executes before you got result from server